# UIView capture one-finger movements but send two-finger pinch to view behind

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, mapkit, uigesturerecognizer

I have an app with an `MKMapView` and an overlay `UIView`, where the user can draw polygons on top of the map, which is done by using the `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved` etc. and then accumulating the touch locations and adding them as a path for a `CAShapeLayer`.`

This works fine, but we also want to be able to pinch to zoom the mapview.

So what we need is the following:

Single finger touch or drag, should be caught by the overlay view and recorded as an input to the polygon that the user is drawing.

Multi finger touches (pinch, rotate etc) should be passed on to the mapview (which is behind the overlay)

What is the smartest way to accomplish this? Apparently neither `hitTest` or `touchesMoved` can tell me how many fingers are put on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like by adding a pan gesture recognizer to the mapview, and set a max limit of 1 finger on it. And set `isUserInteractionEnabled` to `false` in my overlay, which instead got new methods for receiving touch events.

In the action for the pan gesture recognizer, I switch on the recognizer state and send actions to my overlay view, telling that the touches have started, continued or ended. And I set `mapView.isScrollEnabled = false` in all cases except for the cancel, end and failed, where I enable it again, so it works when the user does a two finger pinch/drag etc.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would want to implement [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate/1624214-gesturerecognizer) in your overlay.

```
let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(draggedView(sender:)))
panGesture.delegate = self

@objc func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer,
                             shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    if gestureRecognizer is UIPanGestureRecognizer {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

You check if it is a pinch gesture (or gesture.numberOfTouches > 1) and do not handle it if it is. The event should then bubble up to the map view.

Comment: Thanks for your response but it does not affect the behaviour - the touches that I i catch in my overlay with the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` are never passed on to the gesture recognizers in the `MKMapView` which is placed below. The only way I can currently interact with the mapview, is to disable user interaction on the overlay.

Comment: This works if the `MKMapView` is the superview of your overlay. It must not be then.